# The provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken string Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012

An error occurred while getting provider information from the database. This can be caused by Entity Framework using an incorrect connection string. Check the inner exceptions for details and ensure that the connection string is correct.

Inner Exception: `{"The provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken string."}`

I've searched other threads as there are many with similar errors, but I cannot seem to find a solution.

I am using VS2012 Professional and SQL Server 2012.  I am able to connect to the server using Server explorer using windows authentication.  I am building a webforms application with multiple tiers.  One of them containing my Entity framework tier which contains my Context class.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->

<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>

  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MYSQLSERVER"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
         connectionString="Data Source=myComputer\MYSQLSERVER;Trusted_Connection=true"></add>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

This is what the app.config in my Entity Framework class library layer looks like.

```
<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Also, I have tried changing the app.config defaultConnectionFactory type to

```
<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
```

but it did not change anything.

I am not really sure what any of the changes I am making even mean which worries me.  Sure I could of found the solution online and fixed my issue, but I would really like to understand the web.config and what this all means.  On top of finding a solution to this problem, can anyone point me in the right direction to learning web.configs?

Thank ahead for your help.

Comment: Yeah, was getting this and it apparently was simply that the server name was not correct.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In my case, it was my SQL Server instance that was not running. I simply started the service and everything worked fine. Hope this helps someone down the road.

Comment: Similar on my side, mysql was running, but my database was not created (due to a previous reinstall)

Answer (score 7):

I also faced to this error and I solve that downgrading these NuGet packages

> MySql.Data - 6.9.12
>
> MySQL.Data.Entity - 6.8.8

this is my reference [URL](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=91030) which I referred

Answer (score 4):

Well I fixed it.

Just needed to put "." for localmachine in the data source as follows:

```
<add name="MYSQLSERVER"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
     connectionString="Data Source=.\MYSQLSERVER;Trusted_Connection=true"></add>    
</connectionStrings>
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's another possible cause:
I have both my (ASP.NET) HTTP server and MySQL/Aurora server on AWS (understood that AWS was not part of the OP's comments).
My desktop's (actually, our building's) IP was whitelisted in the MySQL/Aurora server's security group, so everything worked perfectly for development.
But the ASP.NET server's IP was *not* whitelisted for the MySQL/Aurora instance, thus the ASP server's EF connection request was being rejected, and *that* was causing the exception noted at the top of this thread.
Esoteric, but maybe this helps someone.

Comment: I had this exact problem myself

Answer (score 3):

For those getting this recently, in updating to MySql.Data 8.0.19 you also have to update your references for EntityFramework, Oracle changed the package, it's now MySql.Data.EntityFramework instead of MySql.Data.Entity or MySql.Data.Entities.  Props to David Sekar: https://davidsekar.com/asp-net/mysql-error-the-provider-did-not-return-a-providermanifesttoken

Answer (score 1):

For me, It was all of the below.
1. DB not allowed to connect to my dev environment. May be firewall restrictions.
2. Connection string had wrong credentials for the DB.
So generally speaking, incorrect connection string.

Answer (score 0):

..and FINALLY(?!?) don't forget to build your project with 'Prefer 32-bit' checked as this will eliminate the KNOWN BUG which generates this error message (which has the inner exception message = 'Arithemtic overflow')

Answer (score 0):

i meet this problem when i try to connect to mysql, the reason is that i forget to add the "password" in "connectionStrings"

Comment: I faced the same issue and resolved it when i saw your hint i forgot the password, the providers connection string didn't come with it. it just had a placeholder which i had to replace with my password :-)

Answer (score 0):

In my case the paramter was v12.0, I changed to v11.0 and it is working

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, reinstalling Npgsql with the package manager did the trick. 
Seemed to be a versionning problem.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was using double backslash between the server and the instance, such like .\SQLExPRESS;...etc.

The correction was to use .\SQLEXPRESS

hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I often forget why this error comes often. For me its usually I have changed credential of the database and did not change the same on the code section.
Just in case if I come here again to remind myself.